# How to show coordinates in Minecraft PC without F3 button on my Gaming keyboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I know how to show coordinates if I had a f3 button but I own a gaming keyboard and don't have any f keys on it so is there a way to show them or do I need to switch keyboards every time I want to play Minecraft?

Comment: What keyboard do you have that doesn't have an F3 key?

Comment: There are laptop keyboards that don't. OTOH a *gaming* keyboard without function keys is an abomination that should be cast into fire.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers suggest you can use third party programs to rebind a key or key combination to F3.

Other options include the Windows on screen keyboard if you're actually using Windows.

You can install a minimap mod if there is one for whichever version of MC you're playing. They usually display coordinates.

If the mod or an equivalent exists for your MC version, I remember one called something along the lines of "In Game Info XML" which could be configured to display your coordinates as well as other information.

I haven't looked at the controls menu in a while but the debug menu (the F3 menu) might be rebindable in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does your keyboard have a Fn key?  Maybe you can hold down the Fn key and press another key?

There are probably some apps out there to bind other keys to your function keys too.  This article on How To Geek should show you how to do it:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

Essentially, if you're on Windows you can use an open source app called [Sharp Keys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) to rebind things.  So if you don't use the `home` button for example, you could rebind that to F3.

Answer (score -1):

If your keyboard actually has no F keys (which I somewhat doubt), you have a few options to generate an F3 keystroke.

1. Make an AHK script to bind a key combo to F3. This script will bind ALT+3 to generate the F3 key press:

   ```
    !3::
    send {f3}
   ```

Of course you can modify this to be whatever key or key combo you want. I have had very good luck using AHK for this type of problem and I highly recommend it.

2. If you can't or don't want to go to the trouble of installing AHK. You also have the option of using [Windows On-screen Keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10762/windows-use-on-screen-keyboard). This gives you a virtual keyboard that you can use to type key presses, including the F3 key. I have only personally used OSK rarely for doing things like remote troubleshooting and the like. You could have some difficulties using the OSK in game, unless you have a second monitor or are able to run the game in borderless windowed mode.